Are messages from MS SQL Management Studio accessible via SQL Alchemy?
I’m interested in programmatically receiving the messages output in the messages tab in MS SQL Server Management Studio.
This seems to be possible in the pyodbc and pymssql packages, as mentioned here, but I’m looking for an implementation in SQL Alchemy.
Sadly, from what I’ve read in several SO posts like this one, it looks like SQL Alchemy is not designed, intentionally, to return non-table results. But I was hoping someone here might have something to say to the contrary.

We can get at least some of the messages by using a raw DBAPI cursor. For the stored procedure
1> CREATE PROCEDURE so78552281
2> AS
3> BEGIN
4>     SET NOCOUNT ON;
5>     PRINT 'This is a message';
6>     PRINT 'and this is another one.';
7> END
8> go

we can do
from pprint import pprint

import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger^5HHH@msodbcsql18_199")

dbapi_crsr = engine.raw_connection().cursor()
dbapi_crsr.execute("EXEC so78552281")
msgs = dbapi_crsr.messages
pprint(msgs, width=120)
"""
[('[01000] (0)', '[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]This is a message'),
 ('[01000] (0)', '[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]and this is another one.')]
"""

